# Proof by contradiction that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} < \sqrt{15}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, arithmetic, radicals

Claim: $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} < \sqrt{15}$

a) State the negation of the claim.

b) Use proof by contradiction to prove the claim.

Can anyone explain to me how I would do this question?

A [computation suggests](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(15)-sqrt(2)-sqrt(6)) that these numbers are relatively close to each other; $\sqrt{15}-\sqrt2-\sqrt6 \approx 0.01$.